# OPC UA Server - String Node Id Creation

Tags: c#, opc, opc-ua

Project Reference:
https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard

I'm trying to create an OPC UA Server that contains some methods and I need to create a NodeId for each method I want to expose.
Using Integer identifier its works, but with String identifier I'm not able to call the method using an OPC UA client.

Trying with a 3rd part client still not work but the error is missing NodeId, it seems like a numeric node id it's expected.

I'm not sure if it's a bug or just something that escape me. Can someone please clarify my doubts?

Thanks,

NodeId integer created using (Prj: Opc.Ua.Core ,File: Node.cs):

```
    #region public NodeId(uint value, ushort namespaceIndex)
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a guid node identifier with a namespace index.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Creates a new NodeId that will use a numeric (unsigned int) for its Id, but also
    /// specifies which namespace this node should belong to.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="value">The new (numeric) Id for the node being created</param>
    /// <param name="namespaceIndex">The index of the namespace that this node should belong to</param>
    /// <seealso cref="SetNamespaceIndex"/>
    public NodeId(uint value, ushort namespaceIndex)
    {
        m_namespaceIndex = namespaceIndex;
        m_identifierType = IdType.Numeric;
        m_identifier = value;
    }

    #endregion
```

NodeId string created using (Prj: Opc.Ua.Core ,File: Node.cs):

```
     #region public NodeId(string value, ushort namespaceIndex)
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a string node identifier with a namespace index.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Creates a new NodeId that will use a string for its Id, but also
    /// specifies if the Id is a URI, and which namespace this node belongs to.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="value">The new (string) Id for the node being created</param>
    /// <param name="namespaceIndex">The index of the namespace that this node belongs to</param>
    public NodeId(string value, ushort namespaceIndex)
    {
        m_namespaceIndex = namespaceIndex;
        m_identifierType = IdType.String;
        m_identifier     = value;
    }

    #endregion
```

Sample client returns this error:

[Here the error trying to call the method with String NodeId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USKE9.png)

Comment: Add this error as text, or as last resort paste in directly as an image. Secondly add the code on client side, how do you build nodeid.

Comment: The piece of code that you have shared does not really help us to help. Would you share the entire application that you have developed? So, people can fork it and try to reproduce the problem to resolve.